# Django: What is the basic difference beween User and Anonymous user?

Tags: django, django-models

According to my current understanding:

User model represents `superusers` and `staff` members only on the other hand normal visitors visiting site to read content belong to Anonymouse Model. Is that so ?

Django docmentaion is not very clear about this.

I tried googing this but didn't find anything useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is incorrect. The User model is (by default, you can always customise this) used for any registered user, including superusers, staff members and standard users of your django app (if you allow for user registration). An anonymous user is any vistor to your site which isn't logged in, or doesn't have an account.

Comment: Correct, basically everybody who can login to your application is a User instance and everybody who visits without being logged in or without having an account is an anonymous user.

Answer (score 0):

As @dentemm says is correct. You can also find more difference between `User` and `AnonymousUser` from here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymoususer-object